# Using comparator with poker hands: error with compare method

Tags: java, poker

I'm trying to sort poker hands using a custom `compare` function.  A poker hand is represented as a 5-element String array.  I've written a class called `HandComparator` that has a method as follows for comparing hands:

```
//return 1 for a being better hand, return -1 for b being better hand, 0 for tie
public static int winner(String[] a, String[] b) {...}
```

Now I have an array of poker hands (so of type String[][]) and I want to sort them by making use of this `winner` function.

So I have something like this in main:

```
allButtonHands = Arrays.sort(allButtonHands, new HandComparator());
```

and within `HandComparator` I have my `compare` function:

```
public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
    return winner(a, b);
}
```

Unfortunately, Eclipse gives me the following error:

The method compare(String[], String[]) of type HandComparator must override or implement a supertype method.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well how is your `HandComparator` class defined? (And is there any reason you're using `String[]` to represent a hand of cards... I suspect you'll have a better time if you create a class for that, consisting of multiple `Card` references...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to see your HandComparator class, but I guess that is declared

```
public class HandComparator implements Comparator {
```

Try to change to

```
public class HandComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
```

If not, please, post your HandComparator class